# Maven: Determine local jar location

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and am trying to use it to package an existing project. It's a Windows Java utility using a C++ dll but the dll may exist multiple times on the same machine. Other Java projects use this one by referencing the jar - it's not standalone.

Ideally I'd package the dll alongside the jar using a Maven assembly (I think!) but in order to load the dll I'd need to know its location - now part of the local Maven repo.

Is this the right thing to do and if so, how should I go about it?

Thanks for any help,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to install jar to your local repo:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pathToYpurJarFile -DgroupId=mavenGroupId -DartifactId=mavenAtrifactId -Dversion=yourVersion -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets the file into the repo. However, I want to be able to then use the dll in another project. I can add a dependency in the other project's POM but I don't know the location of the dll for calling LoadLibrary in the new project - how do I determine this (or cause the dll to be installed to a known location when it's pulled down as a dependency)?